# How can I implement a moving scene

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to implement a moving scene in OpenGL.

Scene description: terrain is static but all other objects are moving towards the -x axis.

Terrain is a plane in xz plane.

I have a mesh that will appear a lot of times on the terrain in several places.
But all of them will be moving towards -x axis at a specific speed.

I've thought of these possible implementations:

1. Create one mesh only and display it several times (I prefer this one)
2. Create several meshes, save them to a vector and then move them. After they leave the viewport, maybe destroy them?

The problem with the 1st way, is that I'll create meshes with a x% possibility, so this entails not knowing the number of meshes that will be needed. So how can I display them?

In example if I knew I would create 3 meshes I would do this:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(mesh1 position + speed)
mesh.dray();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(mesh2 position + speed)
mesh.dray();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(mesh3 position + speed)
mesh.dray();
glPopMatrix();
```

Now in case we need to create meshes as long as the animation continues, how would I implement that? And secondly, what about the meshes that left the viewport? Do they continue to exist?

Comment: Don't use the fixed function pipeline!

Comment: @FelixK.: You mean don't use the code written above, right?

Comment: The fixed function pipeline is deprecated and should not be used. And it makes it sometimes hard to help somebody. Search on stackoverflow or google for more informations on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is useless if you intend to code this in pure openGL.

However, if you are willing to try a 3rd party library, try www.ogre3d.org - I would find this really very easy to do in ogre.

In fact the challenges on 'intermediate tutorial one', *if* I remember correctly, should address the equivalent ogre concept of the problem you are having with openGL.

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Intermediate+Tutorial+1&structure=Tutorials

*(Would've made this as a comment, only recently became active!)*

Comment: Well, I need to use pure openGL only as it is for an assignment.

Comment: Well sorry..... I have about 20 minutes of pure openGL experience.... perhaps I'll leave it up for the edification of others...

Answer (score 0):

Use option 2. Just dont delete them just move them back and use them again. Like for example if I wanted to count sheep... I wouldnt create 1,000,000 meshs of sheep I would create maybe 1 or 2 and just rotate between using those.

Comment: I'll have to find out how many are going to be needed for the needs of the scene by testing, right? Also, I.must save their position in order to check if they've  passed the left side of the viewport so that I reposition them at the right one..is that correct implementation?